# How to define a user in postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, postgresql

I want to define a variable user similar to this set up in mongoose, except I want to do it in postgreSQL:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
})));
```

Essentially, I have a database currently set up that stores the user information after they register in postgreSQL, but now I want to create sessions that allow me to easily retrieve and display a user's data after the user signs in. In the example that I watched, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvviEA1pOXw&list=UUJI9gByFSXE1ABDRcLQjWgQ) someone used mongoose as their DB and I was not sure how to establish sessions with postgreSQL as they did with mongo.